# Zsh tries to correct a command to a file

Tags: zsh, sudo

Zsh has a feature that lets it prompt for corrections to files in the current directory.  Eg, if I say `cd bar` when I mean to say `cd baz`, then zsh will say: `zsh: correct 'bar' to 'baz' [nyae]?`

Normally, this works fine.  However, sudo seems to mess things up.  Specifically, suppose I want to version control my apache2 directory with git.  I would type something like `sudo git add .`  This is the correct command to run.  However, zsh would prompt me with `zsh: correct 'git' to '.git' [nyae]?` as if it didn't know that git was a command, so it thought I was trying to refer to the .git folder.

Why is this happening?  How can I get it to stop prompting me in those situations?

Thanks!

EDIT: It seems like zsh, by default, will consider all arguments to a command to be files or directories.  However, I know that there is some functionality to extend this.  For instance, if I type `git st`<kbd>tab</kbd>, then zsh will complete it to stash, status, or stripspace (with documentation on each of those).  I would, ideally, like zsh to keep providing tips like these even with something like sudo (so, I would rather not do a nocorrect).  How do I customize that functionality in zsh?

Comment: Strange you notice this only with sudo. I used to see this for `emerge`/`cave`/`paludis`, `eix` (they accept program names as their arguments; and program names are usually identical to their configuration directory names), sometimes `grep`, my own script that launches applications in background and so on. As the result I disabled all of the corrections except command names corrections: `setopt nocorrectall`.

Comment: Problem here is that `sudo` (and `emerge`/…) is a program and `git` is its argument. Zsh corrections expect *only* file (or directory) names in program arguments so any command which accepts something that is not a file name is subject to such problem. And you are right, as `sudo` is not a shell builtin, zsh does not know that `git` is a command.

Comment: Thank you for the info!  I added more of a description to my question.

Comment: There is no such thing as “considering all arguments … by default”. Zsh completion and zsh corrections are different mechanisms and the latter is not configurable. I would also like to see them merged (i.e. corrections using variants from completion) or at least corrections be separately configurable (though this will require more code to write by completion script authors), but this ideas are to be discussed in zsh mailing list. Before the time it is done I will have `setopt correct` with `setopt nocorrectall`.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `nocorrect` before the command itself, or define an alias

```
alias sudo="nocorrect sudo"
```